# Do the Guava Immutable* classes satisfy the standard collection interfaces they implement?

Tags: java, collections, interface, guava, immutability

For instance, if I have an interface like

```
public interface Partition<E> {
    Set<E> getIncluded();
    Set<E> getExcluded();
}
```

And I implement it like so

```
public class ImmutablePartition<E> implements Partition<E> {
    private final ImmutableSet<E> included;
    private final ImmutableSet<E> excluded;

    ImmutablePartition(Set<E> included, Set<E> excluded) {
        this.included = ImmutableSet.copyOf(included);
        this.excluded = ImmutableSet.copyOf(excluded);
    }

    @Override 
    public Set<E> getIncluded() {
        return included;
    }

    @Override
    public Set<E> getExcluded() {
        return excluded;
    }
}
```

Am I really implementing the *spirit* of the original interface? If client code gets a `Set<E>` back, tries to manipulate it, and gets an `UnsupportedOperationException`, surely that defeats the purpose of implementing the `Set<E>` interface in the first place?

This question applies to all Guava Immutable* collections that implement the standard collection interfaces from `java.util`.

**edit:** As I've been reminded below, the `Collection` interface specifies the `UnsupportedOperationException` for unsupported mutation methods. I feel like the *expectation* still is that a returned collection will allow modification, unless otherwise stated. If I wanted to return an immutable collection, I would specify the return type as the immutable class, if possible.

I guess my question is: being that the usual assumption (in my experience) is that a returned collection will be mutable, is it sensible to implement a interface method that returns a general collection and return an immutable collection?

Comment: FYI: the java library also has methods to make a Set immutateble: [`Collections.unmodifiableSet(included)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableSet\(java.util.Set\))

Comment: @Ferrybig The `Collections.unmodifiableSet()` and related methods don't make the collection *immutable*. Instead, they provide an *unmodifiable view* of the original collection. Anyone who has a reference to the original collection can modify it, and those modifications are visible through the view collection. Guava Immutable* collections cannot be modified by anyone.

Comment: "the usual assumption (in my experience) is that a returned collection will be mutable"  This is not a good assumption.  It forces everybody who ever returns a collection to make a defensive copy on every call.

Comment: In general, mutability should be avoided wherever possible. If an interface you're implementing requires (for some reason) that collections returned from methods be mutable, it should explicitly specify that. Your example code is actually a good example of why returning mutable collections would not be a good idea: you'd either need to copy the internal collection every time someone calls a method or return the (mutable) internal collection directly, in which case what's stopping someone from adding an excluded item to the included set?

Comment: There is nothing stopping you from declaring the methods in `ImmutablePartition` as returning `ImmutableSet<E>`, which allows callers to know that the return value is immutable. Obviously this requires them to have a reference to an `ImmutablePartition` specifically - you wouldn't if you just had a `Partition` - but then, you'd only know you are getting back a `Set<E>`, which by contract may throw `UnsupportedOperation` on mutation operations.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't know what the *spirit* of an interface is, but the *specification* (a.k.a. Javadoc ;-) of the Java collection interfaces clearly state that immutable collections may throw an `UnsupportedOperationException` when the user tries to modify them.

**Edit to also answer your edited question**

First, I agree that whether a returned collection is mutable should be documented. However, I disagree that the default assumption is that the collection is mutable. Also when a returned collection is mutable I expect that this is documented, and also that it is documented what happens when I modify the collection (in particular: is the object from which the collection originates modified when I modify the collection, or is it just a copy of some data).

It would maybe be good to have types like `ImmutableSet`, `ImmutableList`, and so on, but the Java standard library doesn't have them. The reason is that the situation is not a boolean: a collection can be partially modifiable, for example because it allows deleting elements but not adding new ones. It would not be a good idea to have seperate interfaces for all possible combinations, and therefore the Java designers decided to have none.

You can use an external library, such as Guava, but this also has disadvantages:

- You introduce a dependency to an external library
- The Guava immutable collections contain a copy of the original data, not a view. If your class just wants to make some internal list public without the possibility that the caller changes the internal data, making a copy every time is probably not what you want.

Comment: Ah, I missed that paragraph. So then should all code that operates on a received collection be prepared to handle the `UnsupportedOperationException`?

Comment: @evanjdooner : code which operate on received collection should be prepared for what if written in javadoc.

Comment: @evanjdooner. Just because the Java type system doesn't know whether a collection is mutable or not doesn't mean *you* don't know it. Often you know whether a method returns a mutable collection or not, for example because the method's Javadoc mentions it. It's the same with other kinds of constraints. For example. if you divide and `int` by `0`, an exception will be thrown. This does not mean that you will check for 0 before every integer division, because often you know that a variable cannot be 0.

Comment: @evanjdooner: A method that receives a collection should either specify that the collection _must_ be mutable and that it may modify that collection or it should not attempt to modify that collection, in which case it doesn't matter if the collection is mutable or not. In neither case should it need to actually handle `UOE`, because in the former case it can just propagate to the user who called the method incorrectly and in the latter it should never happen. In any case, the vast majority of code shouldn't need to modify collections it receives from elsewhere.

Answer (score 5):

`Do the Guava Immutable* classes satisfy the standard collection interfaces they implement?`

**YES**.

Behavior of interface method invocation is implementation specific, until explicitly restricted by documentation.
Throwing `UnsupportedOperationException` is not violation of interface contract.

Example :

`java.util.Collections.UnmodifiableList`, which implements `java.util.List` do following:

```
public void remove() {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}
public void set(E e) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}
public void add(E e) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}
```

If you check javadoc of particular methods of `List` interface eg, `boolean add(E e)` you can find following:

> ```
>   throws UnsupportedOperationException if the add operation
>           is not supported by this list
> ```

Answer (score 1):

`Arrays.asList()` already returns List that does not permit `add()`.

So I guess returning non-modifiable or partially-modifiable collections are OK, judging that Java spirit is defined by Java standard library specification.

Answer (score 1):

It's perfectly valid (and in my view, preferable) to use ImmutableSet as the return type. That clues in human readers that what they're getting will be immutable.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion it doesn't. I know that the documentation states that there are optional operations, and even these methods may throw `UnsupportedOperationException` (which is an unchecked one so the caller might not be prepared for catching it), but I think the purpose of an interface is specifying of *what can be done* with an implementation, and since those methods are present on the interface, they should be properly implemented. If there are optional operations then there should be some API to discover it by code, not by reading the documentations.

I even think that throwing an `UnsupportedOperationException` is violating the [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). Make no mistake, I don't criticize Guava here, this is rather a problem with the standard Java collection framework, the authors of Guava wanted to seamlessly integrate the immutable collections into it and they had to make some compromise.